# WindowManager focus save my life please

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I want move a focus form a view of the `WindowManager` to the other views to quit the application.
But I don't want to use `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE`. Is there any other way to solve this?

for example,

```
public class WindowManagerTest extends Activity 
{      
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.windowmanagertest);

         WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)getSystemService(
            Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
         Display dis = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
         TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
         Point pt = new Point();
         dis.getSize(pt);
         result.setText("width = " + pt.x + "\nheight = " + pt.y +
            "\nrotate = " + dis.getRotation());

         ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
         img.setImageResource(R.drawable.clover);
         WindowManager.LayoutParams param = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
         param.gravity=Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
         param.x = 100;
         param.y = 20;
         param.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
         param.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
         //param.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
         param.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;

         wm.addView(img, param);
   }
}
```

Comment: it's hard to understand what you're asking, you want to change focus from 1 view to another?

Comment: When I create a view of the WindowManger, It has focus and consume all events.. I can't even move focus to the other view by touching them(in spite of android:focusable="true" and android:focusableInTouchMode="true")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you're looking for the following:

```
img.setFocusable(true);
img.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

or set those to false on the window manager?